# \usemodule and ConTeXt

Tags: context, lettrine, modules, drop-cap

I can't seem to use modules in ConTeXt:

```
\usemodule[lettri]

\starttext
\lettrine{T}{his is a test}
\stoptext
```

When I run `texexec` on this, I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \lettrine
             {T}{his is a test}
? X
```

I have a TeX source for lettrine in `/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/third/lettrine/t-lettrine.tex`. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Given the answer to this, might this be closed as too localised? Or is there a problem with the docs that mean that this is still a worthwhile question to have up here (with a more specific title)...

Comment: @Seamus: I think there is a problem with the doc (which say to use `lettri` so other people might find it useful.

Comment: OK. Perhaps you should contact the author of the documentation to get them to fix that?

Comment: @Seamus. I'll see when I have time. I actually didn't switch to ConTeXt eventually so I don't use this personally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `\usemodule[lettri]`

Try:
`\usemodule[lettrine]`

Works here with current minimals (mkii, mkiv)

Answer (score 3):

`\usemodule[lettrine]` works fine for me with the context-minimals after I installed the module. (with context not texexec).